# how to get values from firebase database using flutter

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

I try to experience Firebase Live database with flutter. I just would like to get a value in the datasnapshot of the firebase response.

Comment: Please post the code and explain where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_database/example/lib/main.dart) example application in Flutter's Firebase Database plugin.

Comment: link no longer available

Answer (score 2):

For this you will want to use a `FirebaseAnimatedList`. All you have to do is pass in is the reference to your database then you can access your data using `snapshot.value`.

```
return FirebaseAnimatedList(
    query: FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('users/' + user.uid),
    itemBuilder: (context, snapshot, animation, index) {
      return Row(children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          snapshot.value['source'],
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0),
        ),
      ]);
    });
```